# Elastic Spring And Energy Issue

Tags: homework-and-exercises, spring, elasticity

I`m trying to write an expression ( Work & Energy ) of spring that is not loose and it has a box on it with a weight of 1Kg.
how its should be? this is what I tried to do:
$$\frac{kx^2}{2}-mg$$
this is an illustration of it.
[image]

the $m$ box is $1kg$ and $k=200$ and the state is that the spring is not loose.
I would like to get some advice how to do that. 
thanks!

**EDIT**
Here is my full problem. I want to find the maximum contraction of the spring, The first mass falls on the mass already in the spring.
so I chose to solve it with Work and Energy.
$$mg(3+x_{0})+\frac{k{x_{0}}^2}{2}-mg=\frac{k{x_{0}}^2}{2}-3g$$
this is the right expression to write?
 E$_{end}$=E$_{start}$?

[image: the full problem]

Comment: may you define $k$?

Comment: Elastic coefficient

Comment: and what is $kx^2/2$ and its dimension?

Comment: Work of spring $ W = \int^t_0 Fvdt = \int^t_0 kxv_{x}dt=\frac{1}{2}kx^2$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Work_(physics)

Comment: @OfirAttia : Don't mix variables and numerical values: it is unreadable : When we see an expression, we must check directly if the units are correct, in your expressions, we see together $mg(3+x0), mg, 3g$. This is a nonsense. If you use variables, use variables only. If, at the end, you want to test numerical values, use numerical values for everything, but do not mix the 2.

Comment: @OfirAttia Please do not use separate line equation in comments. Comments are intended to be lightweight and minimally expressive. They are not permanent and they are should not detract from the primary content.

Comment: the expression $\frac {kx^2}2 - mg$ is dimensionally incorrect. $\frac{kx^2}2 $ is in units of work, while $mg$ is in units of force. You cannot subtract the two. Rectify that mistake and you might be able to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

$$W = \int^t_0 Fvdt = \int^t_0 kxv_{x}dt=\frac{1}{2}kx^2$$
$$G=mg$$

Then under static balance:

$W+G=0$

hence:

You are correct!

Comment: ok, if its right to write it like that, I added my full problem in Work and Energy, if you can write me some comments on that. thanks.

Comment: what is your $G$ and your $W$ in the new balance situation?

Comment: @al-Hwarizmi : Same remark as for Ofir Attia (see above) : Don't mix variables and numerical values: it is unreadable. (mg has not the dimension of an energy)

Comment: I am myself meanwhile confused. The set up of the question needs to be really calibrated to a norm of notation. Sorry but cannot help more.